# in wordpress how to redirect root/wp-content or root/wp-content/plugin directory url to home page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How do i redirect a root/wp-content to main index page in wordpress i have installed redirection plugin and define their http://www.heraldsolutions.in/wp-content/ to http://www.heraldsolutions.in/ but it's redirection is not working also we have maintain .htaccess apply rule but it's not redirect on hompage.please help to solve this issue

.htaccess file code :

```
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^wp-content(/.*)?$ / [L,R,NC]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9]{1,4}[.](htm|pdf|jar) default.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
# Redirect /home http://heraldsolutions.in
Redirect /home /index.php
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert this rule in your WP .htaccess before any other rewrite rule (just below `RewriteBase` line):

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content(/.*)?$ / [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: i have update .htaccess code in question please make it correct if it's possible. @anubhava

Comment: So `http://www.heraldsolutions.in/wp-content/` is not getting redirected to `http://www.heraldsolutions.in/` ?

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `wp-content/` folder as well?

Comment: If yes then try placing this rule `RewriteRule ^$ / [L,R]` just after `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: @anubhva i have apply that also but it's not loading home page now & .../wp-content/ redirection is not working

Comment: I have used exact same rule on my WP install and it worked fine.

Comment: it's working in my local wordpress demo too but here i have issue with live site where it's not solving.

Comment: @anubhva yes now i have solved your 2nd given rule i have defined for wp-content .htaccess & 1st given code is for plugins .htaccess now it's working fine thank you

Comment: Oh glad that it worked out for you finally. Please mark the answer á accepted to help out future visitors of this page.